# How can you bind a fast changing data source to a grid without causing a memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, serial-port

At the moment, I have a class containing 8 varying integer objects. These are populated by 1 serial message containing all objects.
The requirement is to create a row of data for every serial message containing each of the 8 objects until a different message is received which clears the message.
I have handlers for both of these, but whatever method I take to use the binding I cannot get around creating a new list each time a row is needed which results in a memory leak / slow garbage collection.

For example this is my latest attempt:

```
public ObservableCollection<Bindings.UCBindings> List { get; set; }
private void NewRowToAdd()
    {
        UCBindings row = new() ;
        List.Add(row);
        row= null; 
    }
private void ResetData()
    {
        List.Clear();
    });
```

And the actual data source binding:

```
public UCBindings()
{
    Bindings = new UCData
    {
        First = = Datasource,
        Second = = Datasource,
        Third = = Datasource,
        Fourth = = Datasource,
        Fifth = = Datasource,
        Sixth = = Datasource,
        Seventh = = Datasource;,
        Eighth = Datasource
    };
}
```

I have looked into binding to a list for each column but I cannot seem to get this working, where I would just add the data to a current list then clear that list when needed.
Ideally I do not want to be creating a new object each time.

For context, I receive a "ResetData" signal every eight of a second, and there can be anywhere between 0 and 30 rows added in that time.

UCBindings and UCData both implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You should create your `ObservableCollection` once and then add, remove entries as required. The `ObservableCollection` is the `datasource` for your `datagrid`. Each entry in the `ObservableCollection` should be one row in your `datagrid`. You will need to define a data template to tie each datagrid column to a single collection entry class property.

Comment: That is what I am trying. However when I add a new entry, I need to do  List.Add(new row()); resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: Can you show me your datagrid view code please. I'm assuming that you're using wpf with your view defind in a xaml file.

Comment: Such a question is difficult to answer as we can't profile your code. The question is: why do you think you are suffering from a memory leak? You rendered scenarion has no potential for a leak. As long the elements in the collections are not referenced by any other object e.g., the elements in the collection observe an event, they will get garbage collected sooner or later. Creating a new ObservableCollection or better reusing the existing may have impact on the overall performance but not in garbage collection of the contained elements. List.Add can never create a leak.

Comment: Just ensure the elements are not referenced e.g., all event handlers are properly detached.

Comment: @OllieSharratt: Why would calling `List.Add(row)` result in a memory leak? You are indeed adding `row` to the heap but that's not a leak.

Comment: Hmmm okay so calling it a memory leak is wrong really, there just seems to be awfully slow garbage collection resulting in gigabytes of memory being used up in minutes! Will update with datagrid code

Comment: When each object has only eight? int properties then you must generate at least multiple millions of items? At what frequency do you create those items? Does not sound reasonable to me that this is the real reason for allocating multiple! Gigabytes! of memory. You should run a memory profiler to identify the true objects that live in the memory and then inspect their incoming references.

Comment: If your objects already implement INotifyPropertyChanged, then why don't you reuse them? Simply update the properties.

Comment: Interesting revelation with this, turns out that there is no memory leak when the app is ran outside of visual studio….